# Read CSV file into C++ with unknown size

Tags: csv, input, vector

I am trying to read in a csv file with an unknown number of rows. I tried using vector of vector approach but it wont compile.

```
  vector<vector<double> > data;      
  ifstream file("data.csv");
  int i = 0;
  while (iss.good())
  {
    vector<int> row; 
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      string val;
      getline(iss, val, ',');

      stringstream convertor(val);
      cout << val << endl;

        row.push_back(val); 
    }
    data.push_back(row);
    i++;
  }
```

Thanks for the tip but even with the edit, the code doesnt compile. Welp.

Error message:

```
Q7.cc:18:10: error: ‘iss’ was not declared in this scope
Q7.cc:28:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<int>::push_back(std::string&)’
```

Comment: it won't compile? post the error message.

Comment: I recently asked a question on SO, got comments and reacted on them interactively, for solving my problem, that worked really nice!

Answer (score 0):

the first line

```
vector<vector<double>> data;
```

has the fragment `>>` which is interpreted as a stream operator. It must look like

```
vector<vector<double> > data;
```

Note the space!